# Magento "Miscellaneous scripts"

Tags: javascript, configuration, magento

@ /index.php/admin/system_config/edit/section/design/

Does adding to Magento's "Miscellaneous scripts" field affect every page in the site frontend?

For instance, if I want lightbox, can I add the script here and then call it anywhere i configure say a Widget or Static Block?

This question came up because JW Player told me they have no specific plans to make a Magento plug-in (like they have for wordpress) but they said that the player "should run" if the script is in the header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes "Miscellaneous Scripts" affects all pages equally. The setting can be different for each store and store view, but will still affect all pages for those stores.

To be more selective you would have to have an extension made for it. You can try asking for volunteers in [Feature Requests](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewforum/11/).

Answer (score 1):

Just make your extension and add JavaScript references to the header in the layout and call the player in your templates.

Comment: I'm wondering about Miscellaneous scripts pane specifically. is that what you reference?